# Configure IIS logging fields in Azure

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-web-app-service

Is there a (new) way to configure which fields should be logged by IIS in Azure (Web Role / Website)? For example, I don't want the *server ip* or the *http referrer* to be logged.

I only found an [older post](http://joelfillmore.com/changing-iis-logging-fields-in-windows-azure/) describing two approaches:

- programmatically set **site.LogFile.LogExtFileFlags** in the *web bole entry point* (this requires the web role to be run in *elevated* mode);
- running an **appcmd**-based script (did not work - infinite wait, sites were never ready :P, perhaps the set-up sequence had changed in the meantime).

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using your web.config file.

See: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httplogging

Comment: But is it possible to configure the logging fields (not the error levels)? They can be configured from the UI, I know...

Comment: @andrei The link I provided to describes how to select which fields to log through web.config.

Comment: Unfortunately, I really didn't find the info on that page. Indeed, it shows how to configure the fields from the UI - not from the configuration file. It seems that it's not possible :(

Answer (score 1):

For Azure Websites (Web apps) you cannot configure IIS logging fields.